# Export df to csv without index in r

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

I would like to export my df to cv without the index

My df:

```
   A B
1  5 8
2  3 3
```

Now I would like to export it without the 1 and 2

My Code:

```
write.csv(customer,"C:/Users/Student/OneDrive/Desktop/Bla/Bla/Result.csv", row.names = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this:

```
write.csv(df,file='Myfile.csv',row.names = F)
```

In your code:

```
write.csv(customer,"C:/Users/Student/OneDrive/Desktop/Bla/Bla/Result.csv", row.names = F)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also do this with fast `fwrite` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
fwrite(df, "Myfile.csv")
```